# Moving a static web page from Google Drive to a PHP friendly environment?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have hosted some pages in Google drive hosting. Working Fine. But I need to add server side scripting.
The  [Google Drive FAQ](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) states, that I can't run server side scripts like PHP, so I need to have an alternative.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Can I keep the pages on Google drive but add scripting from somewhere else?
2. What alternatives do I have to host PHP pages comfortably

Google drive makes live quite easy, since I can create files locally and it takes care of synchronization.

What would you recommend to look at/look for?

Comment: A simple google query "Google drive PHP" leads to this Google document: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en which clearly states: no PHP. You might need to work on your definition of "all over"

Comment: That only is not my question. That somewhat I am clear.. I need alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, server side scripting is not allowed at Drive. Though at Google, you can use Google App Engine for scripting purposes. Many more languages are now supported here, like Go, PHP, Python and Java. You can [learn App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/).

Second thing, to get a better hosting experience, purchase some server space. For learning purposes, you can sign up at many free hosting services. Later switch to the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is not made for what you're trying to do.

You might want to look into [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) or Google App Engine.

Comment: Google cloud is new to me.. Can Google cloud host sites as Google drive do?

Comment: Google Drive cannot host websites. Documents and other static content but nothing dynamic. You really should go with a hosting company. Search for share hosting that's what you need.

Comment: no.. Google drive can host the entire website too in a folder. But it should be static. Not dynamic as you say and limited with the drive size

Answer (score -1):

Google drive simply doesn't allow PHP. It is stated [in the documentation](
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en), which is the first link when you google "Google drive PHP"

To run code on files hosted in Google, you need to use the [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1). It does run PHP, Java, Python, Go.

But it might not be what you are looking for. Using a classic web site hoster might be the better approach

Comment: I have my site in google drive for temporary. Could you please me give some reference to, how can I integrate with drive?

Comment: It might be better If you asked me to search for, "Google APIs" (that's what I needed) rather than you gone for this link and shortening it.

Comment: Thx for downvoting an accurate answer for a cheeky comment :-) you need a regular web site hosting. Trying to stick to Google drive will take you more time. Also as a general rule: asking for "how do I do this" without having investigated references provided isn't considered community friendly. Presuming you did, it would be beneficial to state something like "I had a look at link, link, link but still don't know/understand" etc. Just asking creates the impression of a freeloader. Read the [site etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for more info

Comment: Downvoting is not me. Before asking me to see the site rule, see my reputation. Downvote requires 125 reputation. I can't do it. I won't do it. Its some other. I think u too need to study [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)